# What is the truly rigorous framework to model the success probability of three person shooting gun?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

**Note**: This is not a question about a senior high school book problem.

> Let the success probability of shooting a gun toward a target of three
> people Adam, Bob, Charlie are $0.5$, $0.7$ and $0.9$ respectively. And
> suppose these three people do not affect each other. Compute the
> probability that these three people success simultaneously.

The answer is simply $0.5\times0.7\times0.9$, of course. However, I wonder what is the true underlying framework that we indeed use to solve this problem. In particular, what are the sample space $\Omega$, Borel sets $\Sigma$ and probability measure $P$ (and even random variables) being assumed or used in such context? There are at least three possible framework that come to my mind:

1. **One sample space $\Omega$, Borel set $\Sigma$ and probability measure $P$**: in this case, $\Omega$ should be $\{(i,j,k)\mid i,~j,~k\in\{\text{Hit},\text{Fail}\}\}$, and the event (measurable set) of Adam being hit is $A=\{\{\text{Hit},j,k\}\mid j,~k\in\{\text{Hit},\text{Fail}\}\}$, and $P(A)=0.5$. Follow this construction, we know what we want to solve is $P(A\cap B\cap C)$, which is $P(A)P(B)P(C)$.
2. Interpreting as three **independent random variables** $X_1,~X_2,~X_3$. In this case, $X_1,~X_2,~X_3$ should be inevitable to be defined on **different** probability space, since the probability of three people is varing, so using only **one** measure $P$ for three random variables appears wrong. However according to wikipedia, it seems that we cannot talk about the "independent random variables" on different probability space. Am I wrong? Or can we?
3. Interpreting as the **product of probability spaces**: Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,P_1)$, $(\Omega,\Sigma,P_2)$ and $(\Omega,\Sigma,P_3)$ be three different measure space, such that $\Omega=\{\text{Hit},\text{Fail}\}$, $\Sigma=\{\phi,\Omega,\{\text{Hit}\},\{\text{Fail}\},\{\text{Hit},\text{Fail}\}\}$, $P_1(\{\text{Hit}\})=0.5,~P_1(\{\text{Fail}\})=0.5,~P_1(S)=0$ otherwise. $P_2(\{\text{Hit}\})=0.7,~P_2(\{\text{Fail}\})=0.3,~P_2(S)=0$ otherwise. Finally, $P_3(\{\text{Hit}\})=0.9,~P_3(\{\text{Fail}\})=0.1,~P_3(S)=0$ otherwise. And then we construct the product measure $P$, computing $P((\text{Hit},\text{Hit},\text{Hit}))$.

Which of the above is/are correct? Which is better or worse? What is the most standard way to formalize them? Are there other ways to formalize it?

Comment: I would have thought (1) was a correct formalisation, but unnecessary. Formalisation is designed to provide confidence about the underlying quality of proofs, not to provide insight or to aid calculation. The fact that you can take a problem back to a probability space does not mean you should; nor does it mean there is a single method of formalising a question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea. We have that $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is an abstract probability space. However, we have three random variables $X_n:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ of which we know that
$$\begin{cases}
\mu(X_1^{-1}(\{1\}))=0.5, \, \mu(X_1^{-1}(\{0\}))=0.5 \\
\mu(X_2^{-1}(\{1\}))=0.7, \, \mu(X_2^{-1}(\{0\}))=0.3 \\
\mu(X_3^{-1}(\{1\}))=0.9, \, \mu(X_3^{-1}(\{0\}))=0.1 \\
\end{cases}$$
and that for any $\{B_1,B_2,B_3\}\subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$\mu\bigg(\bigcap_{n=1}^3X_n^{-1}(B_n)\bigg)=\prod_{n=1}^3\mu(X_n^{-1}(B_n))$$
We do not know anything about the original probability space, that is, about the events that lead them to hit or to miss.

Comment: Wow, interesting. So is the involvement of random variables inevitable (or having some advantage that beats the (1)(3))? (Or is it correct to say the (1) and (3) are essentially equivalent to (2) and your way?) I think your way is nice and seems to be the most standard. At the same time, I wonder how other people (textbook authors or probabilitist) treat this problem? I have few books at hand.

Comment: I do feel that (1) is most natural, as suggested in the comments. For example [here](https://www.amazon.com/Measures-Integrals-Martingales-Ren%C3%A9-Schilling/dp/1316620247) the author presents the 'throw of two fair dice' by introducing the set $\Omega = \{(i,k): 1 \leq i,k \leq 6 \}$. However, I think that using random variables is 'closer' to a formalization of reality: philosophically, what we observe could be seen as 'functions' of unknown 'states of the world'. Yours is a quite profound question.